# How to unit test a particular file node.js using jasmine framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine-node

I have a very simple question. How do I unit test a node.js class/function at a different directory location from my root specs folder?

What I mean here is, say I have a specs folder located at root of my project

```
/specs/test-spec.js
```

Here I have a unit test written in jasmine to a helloWorld.js class located in

```
/service/benefits/programs/california/helloWorld.js
```

Contents of **helloWorld.js**

```
var helloWorld = function(){
    return 'hello world';
};
```

Here is my node-jasmine unit test

**helloWorld-spec.js** :

```
describe("Hello World", function() { 

    it("should return string hello world", function() {
        expect(helloWorld()).toEqual('hello world');
    }); 

});
```

The unit test won't pass because it cannot see helloWorld.js, how can I make it see helloWorld.js

Like should I add something like this:

```
var helloWorld = require(../../../../helloWorld.js);
```

I don't even understand what those dots represent? How can I make this work? Anybody? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is most likely wrong. The dots represent a path relative to the current path, every ../ takes it up one level in the folder structure.

Say your 2 folder structures are like this:

```
/root/specs/test-spec.js
/root/service/benefits/programs/california/helloWorld.js
```

if you want to access helloWorld.js in test-spec.js:
the reason you would use the `../` first is to go up one level, in this case from `specs` folder into `root` folder

the result would be: `var helloWorld = require(../service/benefits/programs/california/helloWorld.js);`

however if you were trying to get to test-spec.js from helloWorld.js you would need to traverse back through the folder structure to the root level which is again where the `../` comes in, as we need to go back into california, programs, benefits , service to get to root level:

```
var helloWorld = require(../../../../specs/test-spec.js);
```

This method is called relative paths, where the path is relative to where you are in the folder structure.Alternatively you can use the '/' character to indicate that you want to start at root level if you know your folder is always at root level:

```
var helloWorld = require(/specs/test-spec.js)
```

Hope this clears it up and that I understood your question correctly ;)